# How to clean Heroku dependency cache (unmanaged maven dependencies)

Tags: heroku

I have to use an unmanaged SNAPSHOT dependency in my java/maven heroku app.
I do this using a project-local maven repository as desribed in [this article.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies)

Heroku caches the dependencies between builds. Unfortunatly Heroku does not notice if the SNAPSHOT Version changes and keeps on using the cached dependency. This leads to compilation errors as I depend on changes in the SNAPSHOT version.

*Is there a way to manually or automatically clean this dependency cache?*

I found this [maven plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/changes-report.html) (it does a local build and pushes the resulting artefacts to heroku) but its not really the way I want to do it.

One could argue its a bad practice to use this snapshot dependency in the first place but I think there are other more or less valid reasons for cleaning the cash e.g. leaking storage as the unmanaged dependencies are not even removed if they are deleted from the project local repository.

I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<s>There's a [branch](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/tree/cache_clear) of the [java buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java) that clears maven cache. To use it, configure your app to use the `cache_clear` branch:</s>

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java.git#cache_clear`

===Update===

There's a [plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo) that clears cache on any app. Install it and run the [purge-cache](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge_cache) command.

`$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git`

`$ heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As expected, using the buildpack leads to a pretty lengthy dependency download. Unfortunately I get the following error now:  `Could not transfer artifact <groupId>:<artifactId>:pom:1.3-SNAPSHOT from/to project.local (file:/tmp/build_asdf/repo): Checksum validation failed, expected <abc> but is <xyz>`. Using ´-DcreateChecksum=true´ when building the artifacts didn't help.

Comment: In order to get around the checksum thing its helpful to remove the <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy> from ones (project-local) repository tag.

Comment: I am upvoting for the update. In fact, the historical part should maybe be styled with a strikethrough to indicate that the heroku plugin is by far the preferred way.

Comment: I'm using Django with pip installer, and could NOT get heroku to grab the latest version even if I specified the exact version by commit or branch name. This was a lifesaver.

Comment: Thank you! This was a tremendous help. Thought Heroku builds everything from scratch, but guess not. Is there a way to ensure a dyno does NOT cache anything?

Comment: It's now `heroku plugins:install heroku-repo` to install it.

Answer (score 4):

Login to heroko by console, go to the git repository directory of your app, run the following commands and try to push to the heroku git repository again

```
$ heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_GOALS="clean package"
$ heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="--update-snapshots -DskipTests=true"
```

Now, it will download the latest `SNAPSHOT` from the repository before build.
Refer this [heroku build pack for java](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java) for more details.

You can also configure a custom `settings.xml` for your maven, refer this [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml).

Comment: Better than other answers as it does not require additional plugins, files or hacks

Comment: @MichaelTecourt Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've written plugin with an alternate take: bundling the container + the war image into a git repository base image (for now, its either winstone and/or jetty) which is pushed to Heroku, thus maving easier to deploy (I think) :]

http://cedarhero.ingenieux.com.br/heroku-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but if you're having the same issue with Clojure project (using Leiningen), there's a better way to handle this than purging cache with each build: use `:update :always` property for the repository you're working with. (https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L91)

```
:repositories [["releases" {:url "http://blueant.com/archiva/internal"
                            ;; How often should this repository be checked for
                            ;; snapshot updates? (:daily, :always, or :never)
                            :update :always}]]
```