# Retrieving SNAPSHOT dependency on heroku with scala sbt build tool

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

Heroku does not seem to redownload snapshot dependencies in case they have changed. Other questions here on stackoverflow seem to indicate that, however their solutions all deal with java apps.

I use scala, sbt and play, and have problems transferring these solutions such as in :

[How to clean Heroku dependency cache (unmanaged maven dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449785/how-to-clean-heroku-dependency-cache-unmanaged-maven-dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this buildpack that cleans snapshots for SBT based apps.

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ethul/heroku-buildpack-scala.git#feature-clean-snapshots
```

Originally mentioned here:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/issues/31